# Nested loops for menus (basic c++)

Tags: c++, variables, loops, nested

I'm running into errors where they say that a, q, h, etc aren't declared variables, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Here is an example of my code.

I'm also getting an error where it doesn't recognize userinp inside the while loop, but I'm not sure how to transfer the variable storage from outside the while loop to inside the while loop without declaring a global variable, which I want to avoid.

Last question: I want to be able to have any key immediately return to the main menu after each menu item, but I'm not sure what to use for that.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
//Runs a program with a menu that the user can navigate through different options with via text input

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userinp;
    cout<<"Here is the menu:" << endl;
    cout<<"Help(H)      addIntegers(A)      subDoubles(D)           Quit(Q)";

    cin >> userinp;
    userinp = tolower(userinp);
    while userinp != q //loop while no q is input
    {
        if userinp == h
        {   
            cout <<"This is the help menu. Upon returning to the main menu, input A or a to add 2 intergers." << endl;
            cout <<"Input D or d to subtract 2 doubles. Input Q or q to quit.";
        }
        if userinp == a
        {
            int a, b, result;
            cout <<"Enter two integers:";
            cin << a << b;
            result = a + b;
            cout << "The sum of " << a << " + " << b << " = " << result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while(userinp != 'q') {
```

And this:

```
if(userinp == 'h')
```

And this:

```
if(userinp == 'a')
```

etc., and you probably want to declare `userinp` as a `char` rather than an `int`.

If you want to compare a literal character, you must use single quotes.  If you want to compare a literal string, you need double quotes.  The only compare literal numbers without using quotes.

You also have an error with your input.  Your `>>` should be `<<`. Use `>>` with `cin` and use `<<` with `cout`.

Comment: Also, `cin << a << b;` should be `cin >> a >> b;`. You're including extraneous header files `iomanip`, `algorithm` and `string`. And `ctype.h` should be `cctype` to stick with the c++ specific headers.

Comment: I've used the above changes and added some code, but I've gotten this back from the debugger/builde: http://pastebin.com/RNtECZVJ

Comment: @Sean Fix your link.  Or better yet, edit the new stuff into the original question, or if it's different enough, post a new question.

Comment: Here is also my updated code, for reference. I'll update it at the top, but it always seems to take time to indent everything because it doesn't paste cleanly. http://pastebin.com/5jJkPuG9 

I just don't understand the debugger/builder enough to know what is wrong with the code yet. If anyone could help me with this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

problems with code:
u expect userinp to be a charachter but u have declared as integer
2)conditions for if should be within brackets